# integrate project restful on my project mvc

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, soap

i'm new on **spring webservice REST**. and i want to create two project one for **Back-end** and on this project i'll create my web service (**REST**). and i want to integrate this project on my seconde project **Front-end**. how can i configure that.

i work before with (**Soap**) and i know that i should add this on my Dispatcher-servlet

```
  <bean id="webServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
  <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller" />
  <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller" />
  <property name="defaultUri" value="http://localhost:8080/BE_WebService/endpoints" />
 </bean>
```

but for web Service Rest i can not manage to do the same thing, since i have SEVERAL controller and not a single class as (**Soap**) (endpoint)

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with maven you need to add the dependency at your front-end project.

for example :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>app.domain</artifactId>
    <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

then at your context(front- end) add and import from the context where you declare webservice,

for example:

```
<import resource="classpath*:your_context_webservice_configuration.xml" />
```

then you can inject the bean wherever you want, I hope.

for example:

```
<bean id="controller"  class="package.from.controller.Controller"
        scope="session">
        <property name="webServiceTemplate" ref="webServiceTemplate"/>
```

Comment: big thanks for your Reply. just i want to ask you about the **bean** , if i have many **Controller** i should write many bean? or i write **package.from.controller.***

Comment: your welcome, I use to declare many bean, but you can also use component-scan and annotate controllers and not declare.